# Mongodb geospacial aggregate returns different results using $match vs query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-geospatial

```js
db.units.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.70256, 40.4165 ]
      },
      "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
      "spherical": true,
      "maxDistance": 50000
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "some.field.a": true,
      "otherField": null
    }
  }
]).explain("executionStats");
```

Gives me:

```
nReturned: 671,
          executionTimeMillis: 8,
          totalKeysExamined: 770,
          totalDocsExamined: 671,
```

However:

```js
db.units.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -3.70256, 40.4165 ]
      },
      "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
      "spherical": true,
      "maxDistance": 50000,
      "query": {
        "some.field.a": true,
        "otherField": null
      }
    }
  }
]).explain("executionStats");
```

Gives me:

```
 nReturned: 67,
          executionTimeMillis: 6,
          totalKeysExamined: 770,
          totalDocsExamined: 1342,
```

The first question which comes to my mind is, why the number of returned documents is different?
The second one is, why the `totalDocsExamined` is higher when using `query` of `$geoNear`?

**Updated**
When `query` field of `$geoNear` is used, there is a COLLSCAN to find all documents matching the query filter. Unless you create a compound index with all fields:
`db.units.createIndex({coordinates:'2dsphere', 'some.field.': 1, otherField:1 )`

So it seems like the behavior in case of using `query` is by default a COLLSCAN except if you have a compounded index with the geospatial field plus the ones included in `query`.

Comment: What version of mongodb is this where `db.units.aggregate([...]).explain()` is valid?  `explain()` is a function for a `find()` cursor.  To get stats from an agg pipeline you have to use `db.units.aggregate([...], {explain:true})`

Comment: Using MongoDB:  4.4.6
Using Mongosh:  1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that `query` param of `geoNear` decides the number of docs examined.

> Limits the results to the documents that match the query. The query syntax is the usual MongoDB read operation query syntax.

In your first case, it's considered as pipeline. `geoNear` executes first then `match` stage. Hence the number changes.

Comment: This would explain why the number of docs examined is different...however, the number of docs returned by the query {"some.field.a": true,  "otherField": null} is around 100. So why the second case is examining *more* docs?

Comment: And about the number of returned documents, I still don't understand why are different, could you be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Did you execute the query individually and calculated the matching docs?